# WP custom fields: if has value do this with that value, else do this instead

Tags: php, wordpress

I may be too far in my head at this point to see the solution clearly, but every bit of code I've thrown together so far today isn't working.

**The goal is this:**

I have a custom post type, called product, that has custom fields for every product buy code (think S, M, L, etc.)

Within the custom post editor, a user can enter a product code value, which means that product exists.  If there is not value in that custom field (say, for XL), then that product does NOT exist.

I need to create a table grid for each item that follows with a long line of buy buttons: under the S column, if the product exists, there should be a buy button that links to the product code specified in the custom field; if there isn't, there should be an image that is placed instead that says "unavailable".  Followed by M, L, XL, etc...

Not text, all image assets, with links that need to use the value of the custom field being queried.  For 15 different field options.

I've started with a simple query, to get all of the products, but every attempt to tweak thereafter has been... a mess.

```
<?php 
  query_posts( array(
     'post_type' => array( 'product' ),
     'orderby' => 'title',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'showposts' => 9999999,)  
   ); 
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Any help/pointing in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!

--- EDIT --

This is the latest effort that didn't work: it still only executed the first div block, even if there was no value in the custom field:

```
<?php 
$diamond_code = get_post_custom_values("diamond_mp3_code");
if( $diamond_code != '' ){ ?>
          <div style="max-width:33px; padding:3px; border-right:1px solid #FFF; float:left;     background-image:url(complete/c-bg4.gif)"><a href="http://www.ewebcart.com/cgi-bin/cart.pl?&add=01&item_id=<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'diamond_mp3_code', true ); ?>" target="_self"><img src="complete/c-buy.gif" width="100%" border="0"  /></a>
          </div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <div style="max-width:33px; padding:3px; border-right:1px solid #FFF; float:left; background-image:url(complete/c-bg4.gif)"><img src="complete/c-NA.gif" width="100%" border="0" /></div>
          <?php } ?>
```

Comment: also, as an example, here's what one of the buy blocks would need to spit out:

    <a href="http://www.ewebcart.com/cgi-bin/cart.pl?add=01&item_id=<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gold_code', true ); ?>" target="_self"><img src="images_extra/buymp3.gif" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> " width="47" height="25" border="0"></a>